# Downloading csv to server file path

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask, datatables

I am hosting a Flask application on a Windows server. Within the Flask application, users can filter a data table. This data table is created by mapping the result of an SQL query to a Flask endpoint and the table is displayed using an Ajax request within the Jquery Datatables library.

The user can filter the datatable and then click the button "Export Data". This button click exports the filtered data table to a csv located within the user's downloads folder.

```
  buttons: [
               {
                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                    title: 'Data',
                    text: 'Export Data',
                },
            ]
```

I don't want this csv to be downloaded to the user's downloads folder. I want this csv to be downloaded to the server... for example to a file path like "\server_name\downloads".

I have looked everywhere and I can't figure out how to do this. Any guidance would be very appreciated...

Comment: I think you will probably need to find a different approach. The DataTables export functions all run in the browser (the same as the core DataTables library itself). DataTables export functions do not run on the server, or have the ability to send an exported CSV/XLS/PDF file to the server. The question is tagged as a Flask question, so maybe you can look into Python libraries for generating the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, this should be the solution (it's a little workaround). When the user clicks on the CSV button, instead of downloading it, it will be sent via AJAX to a backend function that will interpret the data sent (in this case the CSV file) and save it somewhere on the server.

```
buttons: [{
        extend: 'excelHtml5',
        title: 'Data',
        text: 'Export Data',
        action: function (e, dt, node, config) {

            //Variable where store the csv file
            let content = "";
            //Cycle all column header
            $.each(dt.data()["context"][0]["aoColumns"], function (indexInArray, valueOfElement) {
                //Adding every single column header to content variable and append ";"
                content += valueOfElement['sTitle'] + ";";
            });
            //After the last column header, remove the last ";" and add carriage return
            content = content.slice(0, -1) + "\n";

            //Cycle all row inside the table
            $.each(dt.data(), function (indexInArray, valueOfElement) {
                //Join every single element of row with ";" and add carriage return
                content += valueOfElement.join(";") + "\n";
            });

            //Create the form that will store the CSV
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', new Blob([content], { type: 'text/csv' }, "file.csv"));

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://httpbin.org/post",//YOUR_BACKEND_METHOD_URL
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    ]
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "dom": 'Blrtip',
    buttons: [{
      extend: 'excelHtml5',
      title: 'Data',
      text: 'Export Data',
      action: function(e, dt, node, config) {

        //Variable where store the csv file
        let content = "";
        //Cycle all column header
        $.each(dt.data()["context"][0]["aoColumns"], function(indexInArray, valueOfElement) {
          //Adding every single column header to content variable and append ";"
          content += valueOfElement['sTitle'] + ";";
        });
        //After the last column header, remove the last ";" and add carriage return
        content = content.slice(0, -1) + "\n";

        //Cycle all row inside the table
        $.each(dt.data(), function(indexInArray, valueOfElement) {
          //Join every single element of row with ";" and add carriage return
          content += valueOfElement.join(";") + "\n";
        });

        //Create the form that will store the CSV
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', new Blob([content], {
          type: 'text/csv'
        }, "file.csv"));

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://httpbin.org/post", //YOUR_BACKEND_METHOD_URL
          data: formData,
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
          }
        });
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 90%/1.45em "Helvetica Neue", HelveticaNeue, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.6.0/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.11.3/b-2.0.1/b-colvis-2.0.1/b-html5-2.0.1/b-print-2.0.1/datatables.min.css" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.6.0/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.11.3/b-2.0.1/b-colvis-2.0.1/b-html5-2.0.1/b-print-2.0.1/datatables.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2011/04/25</td>
          <td>$3,120</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Garrett Winters</td>
          <td>Director</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2011/07/25</td>
          <td>$5,300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ashton Cox</td>
          <td>Technical Author</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2009/01/12</td>
          <td>$4,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2012/03/29</td>
          <td>$3,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jenna Elliott</td>
          <td>Financial Controller</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>33</td>
          <td>2008/11/28</td>
          <td>$5,300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2012/12/02</td>
          <td>$4,525</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>59</td>
          <td>2012/08/06</td>
          <td>$4,080</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>55</td>
          <td>2010/10/14</td>
          <td>$6,730</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>39</td>
          <td>2009/09/15</td>
          <td>$5,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sonya Frost</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>2008/12/13</td>
          <td>$3,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jena Gaines</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2008/12/19</td>
          <td>$5,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
          <td>Financial Controller</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2013/03/03</td>
          <td>$4,200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Charde Marshall</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>36</td>
          <td>2008/10/16</td>
          <td>$5,300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
          <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>43</td>
          <td>2012/12/18</td>
          <td>$4,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>2010/03/17</td>
          <td>$2,875</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michael Silva</td>
          <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2012/11/27</td>
          <td>$3,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Paul Byrd</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2010/06/09</td>
          <td>$5,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gloria Little</td>
          <td>Systems Administrator</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>59</td>
          <td>2009/04/10</td>
          <td>$3,120</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Bradley Greer</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>41</td>
          <td>2012/10/13</td>
          <td>$3,120</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Dai Rios</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>2012/09/26</td>
          <td>$4,200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
          <td>Financial Controller</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2011/09/03</td>
          <td>$4,965</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Yuri Berry</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>40</td>
          <td>2009/06/25</td>
          <td>$3,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Caesar Vance</td>
          <td>Technical Author</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>2011/12/12</td>
          <td>$4,965</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Doris Wilder</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>2010/09/20</td>
          <td>$4,965</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>36</td>
          <td>2009/10/09</td>
          <td>$2,875</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>42</td>
          <td>2010/12/22</td>
          <td>$4,525</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>2010/11/14</td>
          <td>$4,080</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>2011/06/07</td>
          <td>$3,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ebony Grimes</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>48</td>
          <td>2010/03/11</td>
          <td>$2,875</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Russell Chavez</td>
          <td>Director</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>2011/08/14</td>
          <td>$3,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michelle House</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2011/06/02</td>
          <td>$3,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Suki Burks</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>53</td>
          <td>2009/10/22</td>
          <td>$2,875</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
          <td>Technical Author</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>2011/05/07</td>
          <td>$6,730</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
          <td>Technical Author</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2008/10/26</td>
          <td>$6,730</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Martena Mccray</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>46</td>
          <td>2011/03/09</td>
          <td>$4,080</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Unity Butler</td>
          <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/12/09</td>
          <td>$3,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
          <td>Financial Controller</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>51</td>
          <td>2008/12/16</td>
          <td>$4,080</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
          <td>Financial Controller</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>41</td>
          <td>2010/02/12</td>
          <td>$4,200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>62</td>
          <td>2009/02/14</td>
          <td>$4,965</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
          <td>Financial Controller</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2008/12/11</td>
          <td>$4,200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
          <td>Director</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>65</td>
          <td>2008/09/26</td>
          <td>$5,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Miriam Weiss</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2011/02/03</td>
          <td>$4,965</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Bruno Nash</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>38</td>
          <td>2011/05/03</td>
          <td>$4,200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Odessa Jackson</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2009/08/19</td>
          <td>$3,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Thor Walton</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2013/08/11</td>
          <td>$3,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Finn Camacho</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/07/07</td>
          <td>$4,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Elton Baldwin</td>
          <td>Data Coordinator</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2012/04/09</td>
          <td>$6,730</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2010/01/04</td>
          <td>$4,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>56</td>
          <td>2012/06/01</td>
          <td>$5,300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>43</td>
          <td>2013/02/01</td>
          <td>$2,875</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cara Stevens</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>46</td>
          <td>2011/12/06</td>
          <td>$4,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Hermione Butler</td>
          <td>Director</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2011/03/21</td>
          <td>$4,080</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lael Greer</td>
          <td>Systems Administrator</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>2009/02/27</td>
          <td>$3,120</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2010/07/14</td>
          <td>$5,300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Shad Decker</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>51</td>
          <td>2008/11/13</td>
          <td>$5,300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michael Bruce</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>2011/06/27</td>
          <td>$4,080</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Donna Snider</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>2011/01/25</td>
          <td>$3,120</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```